# How is the value of transform.position updated and accessed between different private methods?

Tags: unity

[I followed this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR0e-1UBEOU&t=6111s) but I'm still confused about how the code actually retrieves the value of `transform.position`.

I can understand the `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` code is to transform the screen position to a position in the world based on the camera's view, and it then uses this to update the `transform.position` as in the `private void OnMouseDrag` method.

However, I also learnt that since the method is declared as private, the "transform.position" cannot retrieve the value of "transform.position" in each {}bracket.

So how does the value of "transform.position" in `private void OnMouseUp`, `private void Awake` get updated, unless I misunderstood the concept?

```
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.Assertions.Must;

using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GreenBird : MonoBehaviour

{
    Vector3 _initialPosition;
    private bool _birdWasLaunched;
    [SerializeField]private float _launchPower = 500;

    private void Awake()
    {

        _initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (_birdWasLaunched &&
                 GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude <= 0.1)
        {
            timeSittingAround += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (transform.position.y > 10.00 || 
            transform.position.y < -10.00 || transform.position.x > 10 || transform.position.x <-10)
        {
            string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneName);
        }

       
    }

     void OnMouseDown()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;


    }



    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        Vector2 directionToInitialPosition = _initialPosition - transform.position;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(directionToInitialPosition * _launchPower);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 1;
        _birdWasLaunched = true;


    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "However, I also learnt that since the method is declared as private, the "transform.position" cannot retrieve the value of "transform.position" in each {}bracket." ? That doesn't sound like any rule that actually exists in C#. Are you getting this confused with local temporary variables that only exist in the scope where they're declared?

Comment: Thank for your crystal explanation, your example below gave a clear views of what going on and yes, I'm confused it with local temporary variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're confused about the rules for variable scope.

Take a look at this example:

```
public class Foo {

    // This variable is declared inside the scope of the class.
    // That makes it a "member variable". We allocate one of these variables
    // every time we construct an instance of the class Foo, and it lives
    // and remains accessible as long as that instance does.
    public int memberField;
    
    // This is a method defined inside the scope of the class.
    // We call it a "member function".
    // The "private" means only code in this class is allowed to call the function.
    private void DoSomething() {
    
         // Inside this method, we can read and write to members of the class.
         memberField = memberField + 1;    

         // We can also declare "local temporary variables"
         // to help us do our work inside the function.
         int localVariable = memberField + 1;

         if (memberField + localVariable == 7) { 
             Debug.Log("Seven!");
         }
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse() {
        // Other methods in the class can also read and modify our member variable.
        // They're all accessing the same variable attached to this instance of the class,
        // so changes we make in DoSomething can be seen in DoSomethingElse and vice versa.
        memberField = memberField - 1;

        // But they can't access the temporary variable we declared in DoSomething.
        // localVariable = 3;
        // Uncomment the line above and it will throw an error.
        // We don't have a variable by that name here! (Yet...)

        // We could choose to declare a NEW variable called "localVariable"
        int localVariable = -42;

        // But this has no relationship to the variable in DoSomething.
        // It's a completely different bit of memory that we just called the same name.
    }
}


// We can define a derived class that inherits from the class Foo above.
public class ChildOfFoo : Foo {

    private DoSomethingChildish() {
        // This class's methods are ALSO allowed to use Foo's member variables,
        // because ChildOfFoo IS a kind of Foo, just a specialized version,
        // So it gets all the public or protected members that Foo had.
        // It's just not allowed to use the ones Foo marked as "private".
        memberField = 0;
    }
}
```

So, coming back to your `GreenBird` example:

`transform` is a public member variable of `MonoBehaviour` (or strictly speaking, its grandparent class, `Component`), and `GreenBird` derives from `MonoBehaviour`.

That means all the functions inside `GreenBird` are allowed to access its member variables, including `transform`, and the value is shared between them because they're all looking at the same chunk of memory.

The `private` in front of our method names just means that other classes aren't allowed to call them... *usually*. There's a special exception for Unity's MonoBehaviour message functions like `Start`, `Awake`, `Update`, `OnMouseDown` etc.: Unity looks up these methods using reflection, which works around the normal limitations on who's allowed to call what.